# Create an object in a static function in Mongoose and handle its result from router

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am having trouble understanding the use of `await` in Node with mongoose and express.

Basically I have a page `/profile` where I generate a token for every get request I have, according to the user that is connected:

```
router.get('/profile', requiresLogin, (req, res, next) => {
    User.findById(req.session.userId).exec(function(err, user){
        if(err || !user){
            //Display error and return
            return res.send("Error");
        }

        var token = Token.generateToken(user);
        console.log("Token is: " + token);
        return res.send("Working");
    }
})
```

The function to generate the token is the following:

```
TokenSchema.statics.generateToken = function(user){
    const newToken = new this({
        _userId: user._id,
        token: crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex')
    });
    await newToken.save();
    return newToken;
}
```

And I get an error on the `await` line saying: `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`.

I think the code is quite intuitive, so what I want to accomplish is to have an static function to generate the `Token` objects. Then this function will return and other methods (like the one I posted that gets executed when getting `/profile`) can use it to create new tokens.

Is this the proper way to achieve what I am trying to achieve? I would like recommendations on how to do this code more "nodejs", since I am used to other languages where there are no promises and so on, and this is the best I could come up with. I know it is possible to do with callbacks and so on, but I think they might complicate the code for what it should be with other languages.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** just after posting I saw that removing the `await` does what I expected, but as I have seen in [here](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/save):

> The save() method is asynchronous, so it returns a promise that you can await on.

So I don't really understand how nor why it is working

Comment: Seems like you're on the right track, but you of course need to make the function async, as the error suggests. At that point, you'd need to also make the function consuming it async so you can await the promise it returns.

Comment: @KevinB is that the proper way of doing this though? I don't see the point on doing it asynchronously if then I start waiting for the answer to continue. Is there any advantage in this case to have it async?

Comment: Async/await is just syntactic sugar over using promises and .then, or even callbacks. One way or another, you have to wait for the answer to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [can't use `await` in a non-async funciton](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#description), which means that:

- `generateToken` must be `async`.
- When calling `generateToken` in the request handler, you must also `await` that call.
- Again, you can't use `await` there without marking the anonymous handler function as `async`.

Your handler should look like this:

```
router.get("/profile", requiresLogin, (req, res, next) => {
    User.findById(req.session.userId).exec(async (err, user) => {
        if(err || !user) {
            return res.send("Error");
        }

        const token = await Token.generateToken(user);

        console.log("Token is: " + token);

        return res.send("Working");
    });
});
```

And the token generation function:

```
TokenSchema.statics.generateToken = async function(user) {
    const newToken = new this({
        _userId: user._id,
        token: crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex')
    });

    await newToken.save();

    return newToken;
}
```

You can also use `async/await` with Mongoose (instead of using callbacks), so your handler could look like this:

```
router.get("/profile", requiresLogin, async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findById(req.session.userId).exec();

        if (!user) return res.send("Can't find user.");

        const token = await Token.generateToken(user);

        console.log("Token is: " + token);

        return res.send("Working");       
    } catch (err) {
        return res.send("Error.");
    }
});
```